# Why does my Authorize.Net test account fail using the sample app they provide?

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net, payment-processing

I just signed up for a Authorize.Net test account, and then I downloaded the SDK, installed it into my Tomcat server, and configured the helper.jsp with my test account information, but when I submit the "coffee shopping cart" example they give, it gives me an error that is really vague and I can't figure it out.   Any ideas on how I can debug this?

```
We're sorry, but we can't process your order at this time due to the following error:

Transactions of this market type cannot be processed on this system. 
response code 3 
response reason code 87
```

The response code documentation is here:
http://www.authorize.net/support/merchant/Transaction_Response/Response_Reason_Codes_and_Response_Reason_Text.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you got a retail test account and not an ecommerce test account. Either get a new test account for ecommerce or see if you can get Authnet to change the account type for your current test account.

Comment: Thanks.  You were somewhat correct.   When I initially signed up for the test account it asked me for a "card present" or "card not present" account type.   Logic told me to choose the "card present" type, but it turns out that the one that works in this case is the "card not present" account type.  I wish the page would have told me this , but with your help I figured it out.  Thanks!