# Transaction of this market type cannot be processed on this system

Tags: joomla, authorize.net, activemerchant

I am getting this error in my Joomla setup with Authorize.Net. I am trying to use a test account here. Does any one knows what the issue is here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my Authorize.Net test account fail using the sample app they provide?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767107/why-does-my-authorize-net-test-account-fail-using-the-sample-app-they-provide)

Answer (score 4):

You probably have a card present account. You need to have a card not present account. You can [sign up for a card not present account on their website](https://developer.authorize.net/testaccount/).